# Entity Framework 6.x Code First 0..1 : many mapping without explicit FK property - can it be done?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I think I can illustrate this issue without having to define the classes, as the actual structure beyond the foreign key and navigation properties does not seem to have any bearing.

In my derived `EntityTypeConfiguration` class, Entity Framework will let me do this if I want a 1-many relationship with no FK property defined:

```
HasRequired(r => r.Foo)
    .WithMany(); //No explicit foreign key property, navigation property only
```

If I want a 0..1-many relationship, I can do this with an explicit nullable FK property, for instance `public int? Foo_Id {get; set;}`:

```
HasOptional(r => r.Foo)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(r=>r.Foo_Id); //Nullable explicit foreign key property and navigation property
```

but I *cannot* configure a 0..1-many relationship without an explicitly defined FK property the way I can with a 1-many relationship:

```
HasOptional(r => r.Foo)
    .WithMany(); ////No explicit foreign key property, navigation property only, causes runtime error
```

The error I receive on the last example is something akin to this:

> Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in Role 'Bar_Foo_Target' in relationship 'Bar_Foo'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'.

It seems pretty apparent that the error doesn't match the mapping. I know that this can pop up if you try to configure a 0..1-many relationship where the FK property is not made nullable, but that's not the case here, because there is no FK property defined on the class.

Am I missing something? Is this a bug? Why can I configure a 1-many relationship and EF successfully deduces the FK, but on a 0..1-many it craps the bed without an explicitly defined nullable FK property on my class?

Comment: Actually the last example works. Just try and see in a clean environment. Most probably the problem you see is from automatic migration, and they seem to not be able to work with such model transformations.

Comment: @IvanStoev This project is currently in development and we're using a DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges initializer.

Comment: @joelmdev I don't know what are you using, what I'm saying is that creating 2 simple entities `public class Foo { public int Id { get; set; } }`, `public class FooBar { public int Id { get; set; } public Foo Foo { get; set; } }` and using `modelBuilder.Entity<FooBar>().HasOptional(e => e.Foo).WithMany();` just works in clean environment.